# linux: after successfully installing zsh with oh-my-zsh, other users on my system can no longer talk or write me

Tags: linux, zsh, bsd

I previously used bash, and when one of my users sent me a talk request (when I had mesg y) I could see it in the console and it would beep my pc speaker. I installed `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` with success on both, but now, talk or write requests are rejected and not shown to me, and mesg still tells me it is set to yes. I set `zsh` to default using `chsh`.